# Wordpress get current time error on functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I want to get the current time of wordpress, but I got errors, how to fix it? is there another way to get the current time of the wordpress?, I want the time that wordpress using with format (+GMT) and what the user choose, not the server time.

This is my code

```
<?php

require_once( '/wp-includes/functions.php' ); 
$format = get_option('date_format') . ' ' . get_option('time_format');
print date_i18n($format, current_time('timestamp'));

?>
```

These are the errors

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' in C:\xampp1\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\functions.php on line 8

Notice: Use of undefined constant WPINC - assumed 'WPINC' in C:\xampp1\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\functions.php on line 8

Warning: require(ABSPATHWPINC/option.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\functions.php on line 8

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'ABSPATHWPINC/option.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp1\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp1\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\functions.php on line 8
```

Comment: Are you using the code within Wordpress? Why you have included the `functions.php` file from `wp-includes`?

Comment: the date_i18n function are in functions.php , http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include `require_once( '/wp-includes/functions.php' );`. Directly use the function it will return GMT time like below

```
<?php echo current_time( 'mysql', 1 ); ?>
```

For more Please refer this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function current_time() in C:\xampp1\htdocs\wp\time.php on line 1

Comment: @Delta7 Have you include the wp-includes/functions.php file ?